# How to customize org-latex-export-to-pdf?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have a text file that I want to turn into a pdf. I found org-latex-export-to-pdf so I've saved the text file as an org file and when I run the command `M-x org-latex-export-to-pdf` I get a pdf file but I want to go more into how to customize the look of the resulting pdf. Looking at the .tex (LaTex) file I see there there is

```
% Created 2016-06-25 Sat 00:20
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Me},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 24.5.3 (Org mode 8.3.4)},
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
```

Is there an emacs variable for setting the documentclass part of the latex file? Setting a default for org-latex-export-to-pdf so I don't have to include the headers defined [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-and-sectioning.html#Header-and-sectioning) My goal is mainly changing textsize, font type, taking out page numbers, space after paragraph.

Side question as well, from the looking around I see that you can install external packages such as [org-article](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/article-class.html), [XeTex then follow this blog](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/04/nice-looking-pdfs-with-org-mode-and.html) but what is the bare minimum to be able to make the above changes? Are those extra packages even needed?

**EDIT**: The usepackage lines I'll probably have to look at later but for now I'm mainly concerned with the documentclass. To start, I've tried adding

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [44pt]
```

but the font size doesn't seem to change in the resulting exported pdf file though I do see this at the top of the .tex file (the text in the pdf still looks like 11pt)

```
% Created 2016-06-26 Sun 16:31
\documentclass[44pt]{article}
```

Comment: The `article` latex class *does not* allow arbitrary font sizes. IIRC only 10pt, 11pt and 12pt can be used. So it's not Emacs/Org-mode fault.

Comment: @VanLaser Would you know which class would be appropriate for me? I want to simply modify a few things, i.e. font size, font, no page numbers, and adding space between newlines. Looking through all alternative classes here is a bit daunting being a newbie. Is it possible to create my own class for me to use without going through Latex? What is the simplest way to accomplish fontsize/font/nopagenumbers/spacebetween newlines changes?

Comment: The following (short) video is not exactly what you have searched for, but imo it is a pretty nice solution for your problem:
[Perfect Emacs Org Mode Exports to LaTeX – Straightforward Emacs by Jake B](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qHloGTT8XE)

Answer (score 5):

The `\documentclass` part of the export is controlled by: `org-latex-classes`, `org-latex-default-class` and the class specified in the org file using `#+LATEX_CLASS`.  Only classes listed in `org-latex-classes` can be used in `org-latex-default-class` or `#+LATEX_CLASS`.

The class options are given in the second element of each `org-latex-classes` entry.  If you want to add more classes you can modify the existing entries, changing only the class name and options.  `amsart` is a common alternative to `article`.

Additional packages can be added to `org-latex-packages-alist` to have them included in every export.  In my opinion it is better not to modify this, as it hurts the portability of all your documents.

Answer (score 3):

I take a different approach.  I export the Org file without the header (`C-c C-e C-b h l`, and `\input` the resulting latex code in my own `main.tex`.

This gives me full flexibility on LaTeX rendering.

Regarding the document class: you're doing it fine, but 44pt is not a valid option for the `article` class. This is a LaTeX issue.